# How to Convert Numeric Data into Currency in R?

Tags: r, rename, currency, numeric

Searched Google and SO and couldn't find a good answer. I have the following table:

```
      Country     Value
23    Bolivia  2575.684
71     Guyana  3584.693
125  Paraguay  3878.150
49    Ecuador  5647.638
126      Peru  6825.461
38   Colombia  7752.168
151  Suriname  9376.495
25     Brazil 11346.796
7   Argentina 11610.220
171 Venezuela 12766.725
168   Uruguay 14702.505
37      Chile 15363.098
```

All values are in US dollars - I'd like to add in the dollar signs and the commas. Bolivia's value should therefore read $2,575.684. Also, is there any real need to change row names to 1 through 12? If so, an easy way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? You want to first get the correct currency symbol for each country and then you want to add that to the existing numeric value? Is it good enough to add the country currency code (for example, for Bolivia, BOB 2,575.684)?

Comment: To get rid of the row names, just do `rownames(mydf) <- NULL`.

Comment: Edited for clarity. All values are in US dollars; I just want to add in the dollar signs and the commas.

Comment: `paste('$',formatC(df$Value, big.mark=',', format = 'f'))`?

Comment: `library(scales); dollar(dat$Value)`

Comment: Codoremifa: Yours worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Codoremifa, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Posted. The OP said he didn't find the answer on Google, etc. so I wondered if I had understood it correctly :).

Answer (score 12):

```
paste('$',formatC(df$Value, big.mark=',', format = 'f'))
```

Comment: I thought one is a wrapper for the other or something like that, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't give you much of an advantage here, I guess.